# URI.create has an invalid character `\`

Tags: java

```
URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:" + myJarFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

I need this `URI` for using the ZIP `FileSystem` to modify a .JAR file.

Anyway, this works on Mac. But on Windows I'm told that there is a invalid character. The character happens to be `\`.

So what should I do for it to work on Windows and Mac?

Comment: I'm pretty sure backslashes are completely disallowed in the URI syntax. So you'd have to translate them to forward slashes manually. You can do this with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char).

Comment: Why not `"jar:" + myJarFile.toURI()`?

Comment: This works on Mac … until you have a file with a space in its name, or a curly brace, or any other character which is not legal in a URI.  immibis is right, use the toURI() method.